# Initializing const char * in constructor - will there be a memory leak?

Tags: c++

Here is the code which I got:

```
struct ChoiceLine
{
    const char *prompt;
    ChoiceLine(const char *pr):
        prompt(pr)   //can this cause a memory leak?
    {
        ;
    }
};
```

...

```
ChoiceLine choiceLine("hello world");
```

So is it OK to initialize a `const char*` with another `const char*`?

PS: I know about `std::string`, which unfortunately does not fit my purposes.

Comment: There won't be any memory leak here because you do not allocate any memory at all in this piece of code.

Comment: Ok, thank you guys! Cant upvote yet unfortunately...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes that's fine if a little unsafe: the memory associated with `prompt` is not owned by the class instance.

(In your particular case `ChoiceLine choiceLine("hello world");` all will be well since the string literal will last the life of the program).

Hence it would have to be kept in scope for as long as the class instance was in scope.

If I were you I'd use a `std::string` as your class member and suffer a deep copy.

Comment: How do you know they need a deep copy?

Comment: I don't. But one day they might initialise a class instance in another way. Boom! (PS congratulations on the 100k reputation ;-) )

Comment: Thanks, good point! The class won't do much though, it will be just used to construct a menu :).

Comment: It's good advice, because it de-couples the object from the C string argument, which is passed as a `const`, but need not be a const / read-only data itself; which doesn't reflect the semantic intent of `prompt` as a constant.

Comment: Don't worry too much about 'deep copies' either. Most `std::string` implementations use short string optimization (SSO).

Comment: @BrettHale Which is fine for prompts, but is not without problems elsewhere.  (In at least one case, we've had to forgo `std::string` because the implementation used SSO.)

Answer (score 4):

There is no dynamic memory allocation, so there is no memory leak. Your data member just points to a string literal. It is the equivalent of doing this:

```
const char* c = "Hello, World!";
```

Answer (score 1):

No  there's no memory leak, because nothing is being dynamically allocated.

The space required for 'prompt' is just a pointer, and that's effectively allocated by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

No memory leak. Untill you allocate some memory dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on why you cannot use `std::string`, and what your
class is supposed to do.  As you've written it, it basically
leaves the memory management to the caller; typically, such
classes are used when the only reasonable arguments would be
string literals (which have static lifetime).  In other
contexts, I've used such classes to manage pointers to strings
(or other things) returned by libraries using a C interface; in
such cases, the whole purpose of the class is to free the string
in its destructor (often by calling a specific function in the
library interface, rather than `delete[]` or `free`).

The names in your example suggest that you are in the first
case: a `prompt` is almost certainly a string literal or
a string looked up in a dictionary with static lifetime (for
internationalization purposes); in either case, it would be an
error to attempt to delete or free it.